# MonoTouch custom Binding is not working for some methods in Delegate

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios

I have the following protocol to a native library for which I'm attempting to write a MonoTouch binding for (it also has an interface part called Brsp).

```
@protocol BrspDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)brsp:(Brsp*)brsp OpenStatusChanged:(BOOL)isOpen;
- (void)brsp:(Brsp*)brsp SendingStatusChanged:(BOOL)isSending;
@optional
- (void)brspDataReceived:(Brsp*)brsp;
- (void)brsp:(Brsp*)brsp ErrorReceived:(NSError*)error;
- (void)brspModeChanged:(Brsp*)brsp BRSPMode:(BrspMode)mode;
@end
```

MonoTouch Binding:

```
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
[Model]
interface BrspDelegate 
{
    [Abstract]
    [Export("brsp:OpenStatusChanged:"), EventArgs("OpenStatus")]
    void OpenStatusChanged(Brsp brsp, bool isOpen);

    [Abstract]
    [Export("brsp:SendingStatusChanged:"), EventArgs("SendingStatus")]
    void SendingStatusChanged(Brsp brsp, bool isSending);

    [Export("brspDataReceived:")]
    void DataReceived(Brsp brsp);

    [Export("brsp:ErrorReceived:"), EventArgs("Error")]
    void ErrorReceived(Brsp brsp, NSError error);

    [Export("brspModeChanged:"), EventArgs("Mode")]
    void ModeChanged(Brsp brsp, BrspMode mode);
}
```

The open status, sending status and error received methods are being called, but the mode changed does not work. So the Delegate is referenced right in the Brsp class, so that part should work. At one point I got the modechanged also working, so I do know that is called when I call "changeMode" on the Brsp class. But then I messed it up and now it does not work anymore...

Also, right now I'm using the Delegate private class, instead of the event based approach. Because when I try to hook up the generated events for one the above methods, the application crashes without any error or warning from MonoTouch.

I suspect something is not 100% right with the binding, so the methods are not glued together right, but I have tried many, many different things and AFAIK this should work...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding for

```
- (void)brspModeChanged:(Brsp*)brsp BRSPMode:(BrspMode)mode;
```

is missing a parameter. Try:

```
[Export("brspModeChanged:BRSPMode:"), EventArgs("Mode")]
void ModeChanged(Brsp brsp, BrspMode mode);
```

Comment: That helped for the Mode! I thought I had already tried that as well, but after doing so much stuff I may have overlooked it.

Comment: Any ideas why the event handlers crash the app?

Comment: @Rogier EventArgs aren't  crashing your app, Not `Exporting` the right `Selector name` on your bindings is indeed crashing your app, since MTouch is not finding the right symbol name on the ObjC world.

Comment: `OFFTOPIC` @Krumelur I'm back!! :)

Comment: @dalexsoto: not sure what you mean exactly, I have posted a new question about this part, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308585/generated-binding-events-crash-monotouch