# Generated binding events crash MonoTouch

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios

I have a binding for Bluetooth BLE device with the following binding:

```
[BaseType (typeof (CBPeripheralDelegate), Delegates=new string [] {"WeakDelegate"}, 
 Events=new Type [] { typeof (BrspDelegate) })]
interface Brsp
{
    //@property (nonatomic, weak) id <BrspDelegate> delegate;
    [Export ("delegate")]
    [NullAllowed]
    BrspDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

    [Wrap ("WeakDelegate")]
    [NullAllowed]
    NSObject WeakDelegate { get; set; }

    ...other stuff

}
```

And the following delegate:

```
    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
    [Model]
    interface BrspDelegate 
    {
         [Abstract]
         [Export("brsp:OpenStatusChanged:"), EventArgs("OpenStatus")]

         ...other stuff
    }
```

When I hook up a generated event handler for the openstatuschanged, it instantly crashes the app and I get no feedback whatsoever what could be wrong. I'm still a newbie to binding, so...

I have the feeling somehow I made mistake with "Events = ..." part, any ideas?

Thanks,

Rogier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say without more details (e.g. symbolicated crash log) but part of your bindings are inverted (and that could cause endless recursion that will crash your app).

- your `Delegate` method should have the `[Wrap]` attribute (on `WeakDelegate`); and
- your `WeakDelegate` method should be the one with the `[Export]` attribute on the `delegate` selector.

E.g.

```
    [Wrap ("WeakDelegate")]
    StronglyTypedDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

    [Export ("delegate")][NullAllowed]
    NSObject WeakDelegate { get; set; }
```

Comment: This was exactly the problem! I was puzzled a bit at this part, and probably made a mistake when copying/adapting the code. RTFM, as it is correctly shown in the Xamarin docs. Thanks!